# Printing variable doesn't print \ | / -

Tags: bash, windows, echo, special-characters

I am capturing Kafka startup script output into variable and while starting Kafka prints \ | / - to simulate spinning line. So when I do:

```
res=`./confluent start kafka`
echo $res
```

The result is:

```
kafka is [UP][UP] Starting kafka
```

But when I do:

```
echo $res > /tmp/res.txt
```

And open this file on Windows I get:

```
Starting zookeeper 
\
|
/
-
\
|
/
-
\
|
/
-
\
|
/
-
\
|
/
-
\zookeeper is [[0;32mUP[0m] Starting kafka 
|
/
-
\
|
/
-
\
|
/
-
\
|
/
-
\
|
/
-
\
|
/
-
\
|
/
-
\
|
/
-
\
|
/
-kafka is [[0;32mUP[0m]
```

When I open this file on Linux I get the sam result as with `echo`:

```
kafka is [UP][UP] Starting kafka
```

Why those characters are only visible on Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `echo "$res" | hexdump -C` or `hexdump -C /tmp/res.txt` - I'll bet you see lots of hex `0d` bytes (carriage returns), one before or after each  `\`, `|`, `/`, and `-`.

Why?  A carriage-return without a line-feed returns the cursor to the beginning of the line, and anything printed after it overwrites what was already there.

Doing this is a common way to implement a text spinner at the beginning of a line (if done at the end of a line, the trick is to **NOT** print a LF or CR, and to use a Backspace character (`^H`, aka <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>, ASCII character 0x08) after each of the spinner characters, often with a small delay first.

Note: it's not uncommon to also see terminal control sequences like Erase Line (`<ESC>[2K` or hex `1b 5b 32 4b` on a vt-100 compatible terminal) or Erase To End Of Line (`ESC[K` or hex `1b 5b 4b`) near each carriage return.  That's unlikely in this case, because they'd probably show up in some mangled form in the Windows editor.

In other words, the characters **are** in the output, they're just overwritten too fast for you to see.  Your windows editor is probably "helpfully" converting the CRs to CR-LF.

BTW, unix uses LF only to end a line of text. Windows uses CR-LF.  Old, pre-unix, Macs used to use CR only.

Comment: The unquoted `echo $res` they used would already trash any newlines (LF) in the output file (they'll get changed to spaces), so the hexdumps of `echo "$res"` and the file they saved first would probably appear different.

Comment: unlike line-feeds, carriage returns pass through unscathed by lack of quoting (at least in bash. probably others too).  e.g. try `res=$'x\015y\015z' ; echo $res > res.txt ; hexdump -C res.txt`

Comment: yep (it depends on `IFS`). I just meant that it might be worth noting that the `$()`+unquoted echo already changes the output from what the command actually prints if they run it directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using cat, Linux plays back the cursor control characters that make the terminal overwrite the intermediate outputs.  Try `cat -tv res.txt`.

Also, it's good form to double-quote your captures, and use $() instead of `` (assuming bash, ash or similar modern shell) to avoid spawning a new shell process, as in `res="$( ./confluent start kafka )"`